# Python - displaying data when using classes

Tags: python, list, class, object, import

I am looking to work out how to get the name of the budget to appear in the output - the code creates a list (name of budget and budget amount) and appends these as list items to a main list.  I realise importing the `Budget` class to the app file is the way of accessing functionality but I am wondering how to extract the data created within the app file so the repr

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"The budget is {self.balance}."
```

can return the name of the budget in the list

---

I have two files:  ***budget_app.py*** and another ***budget_class.py***

---

**The app file uses the exec function to append new items to a list**

```
from budget_class import Budget

list = []

def createBudget(): 
    list2 = []
    addbudgetname = input("Name the budget:")
    exec1 = f"{addbudgetname} = Budget({int(input('How much to add to budget:'))})"
    exec(exec1)
    exec2 = f"list2.append({addbudgetname})"
    exec(exec2)
    return(list2)


list.append(createBudget())
list.append(createBudget())



for item in list:
    print(item)
```

---

**The class file initializes the Budget**

```
class Budget():

    class Budget():
        def __init__(self, balance):
            self.balance = balance
            
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return f"The budget is {self.balance}."
```

I am trying to work out a way of getting the name of the budget to appear in the output, which is currently

```
How much to add to budget:60

Name the budget:apples

How much to add to budget:800

[The budget is 60.]

[The budget is 800.]
```

Comment: Why are you using `exec()`? Just assign the class instance to an ordinary variable.

Answer (score 0):

The class structure is suboptimal, I would suggest to make a complete refactor, something as the following:

```
class Budget():
    def __init__(self, balance=0, name=None, list2=[] ):
        self.balance = balance
        self.name = name
        self.list2 = list2
        
    def createBudget(self): 
        self.name = input("Name the budget:")
        self.list2.append(input("How much to add to budget:"))
    
    def add_to_balance(self, to_add):
        self.balance += to_add
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"The budget is {self.balance}. and the name {self.name}" 

budget1 = Budget(0,'name1',[1,2])
budget2 = Budget(4,'name2',[1,5])
budged_list = [budget1,budget2]
```

Now you can instantiate the class directly with the arguments or add them with your input support, you can also print the name etc.

Comment: thanks very much I will have a look at this later on